# Как достать jpeg из javascript-а?

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser, jpeg

Для поиска картинок на web-странице используется **WebBrowser** для парсинга и **WebClient** для сохранения.

Прямого адреса оригинала картинки на странице нет, а ссылка ведет на javascript, который, если открывать ссылку в браузере, показывает нужную картинку и только её. 
Сохранение же этой ссылки **WebClient**-ом, понятно, дает текст скрипта, а не саму картинку.

Можно ли средствами **WebBrowser** получить от скрипта **jpeg** и сохранить? Желательно - без отрисовки, для скорости.

Comment: Судя по всему, вам поможет это: [раз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28VS.85%29.aspx), [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Возможно, подойдёт использовать совет из секции "Controlling Navigation" и перехватить запрос на картинку.

Comment: А что в этом JS? Какой код?

Comment: @VladD, Ну, я понимаю, что где-то в недрах IE что-то такое должно быть. Почему и спрашиваю. :) Но писать собственное расширение для этой цели как то через чур. Нет ли метода типа JustRunJS, который бы возвращал искомое?

Comment: @iproger,  в этом JS есть даже полный путь к картинке, но такая халява бывает не всегда. Иногда, кроме как выполнить скрипт, другого пути нет.